# find all users with personal web pages on a server

Tags: linux, webserver, www

for a homework question for a class, I have been tasked with finding all grad/undergrad students that have a webpage on the schools server.

There must be a list somewhere, but I can not figure out where something like that would be.

he set up is pretty standard. To list all grads/ undergrads with an account I can just go to /home/undergrad or /home/graduate, but I don't know how I would find out who has a web page there.

I would use locate to find all the www directories, but that only work on world readable directories. Does anyone know at least what the file name i should be looking for is?

Answer (score 0):

Personal web pages are usually in a directory called public_html in /home. That would be my guess at least.

You could use find to find them all within /home

```
find /home 2>/dev/null -type d -name public_html
```

- **/home** is the directory to search within
- **2>/dev/null** hides all error messages
- **-type d** tells find to search for directories
- **-name** is the name of the directory to search for.

That would give you a list of all directories named public_html. You could also search for index files instead with

```
find /home 2>/dev/null -type f -name index.*
```

that should give you a list of all index files with any extension as we use the wild card.

If that works but you only need a list of names you can pipe the results of the find command to awk like this:

```
find /home 2>/dev/null -type f -name index.* | awk -F/ '{print $3}'
```

- **-F/** tells awk to separate the line to parts after /.
- **{print $1}** is what comes before the first /
- **{print $2}** is what comes before the second /
- **{print $3}** is what comes before the third /

So the command above would only give results inside /home/. The names of the home directories.